# Lambda Function Using Unknown Parameter

Tags: c#, lambda

I see PRISM declaring the following constructor, and I don't understand what's that "o" being used with the lambda function that serves as the second parameter when the base constructor is called:

```
public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeMethod)
    : this(executeMethod, (o)=>true)
{            
}
```

I'd appreciate an explanation.

Comment: it's just an input parameter to a predicate that is not used - in this case the predicate always returns true - I suspect that is a default in case no predicate is passed in.

Comment: this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882516.aspx) will help you to understand anonymous methods and lambda. BTW it is just an input parameter.

Answer (score 11):

The constructor which declaration you posted calls another constructor, so to explain it, we should first look at the other constructor’s signature:

```
public DelegateCommand(Action<T> executeMethod, Func<T, bool> canExecuteMethod)
```

So the second parameter is a `Func<T, bool>`. That means it is a function that takes a parameter of type `T` and returns a boolean.

Now if you look at the lambda that is used:

```
(o) => true
```

Lambdas in general have the syntax `(parameter-list) => lambda-body`, so in this case, the single parameter of the lambda is a variable `o` (which type is inferred to be `T`) and the function returns a constant result `true`.

The purpose of this is to basically make a command that is always executable.

Of course that lambda could look a lot more complicated, so when using the DelegateCommand, you are likely to use more complex and non-constant expressions. For example:

```
 new DelegateCommand(DoSomething, o => o.SomeProperty >= 0 && o.SomeProperty < 10 && o.SomeBoolProperty)
```

Comment: I know what lambda functions are, and am familiar with PRISM and this base constructor (that may be used whenever a command is always activa). I just asked about the SYNTAX. You answered by saying "in this case, the single parameter of the lambda is a variable o (which type is inferred to be T)", but I still don't understand why "o", as the single parameter was already given the name "executeMethod". Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Ofer The whole expression `(o) => true` is of type `Func<T, bool>` and is the value for the constructor parameter `canExecuteMethod`. `o` is just the variable name, freely chosen in this case, that takes the function argument of the `Func<T, bool>` parameter. You could as well name it `parameterToTheCanExecuteMethod` instead: `(parameterToTheCanExecuteMethod) => true`. If it makes the distrinction more clear, you could also add additional parentheses: `... : this(executeMethod, ((parameterToTheCanExecuteMethod)=>true))`.

Answer (score 3):

It calls this constructor:

```
DelegateCommand<T>(Action<T>, Func<T, Boolean>)
```

Passing a lambda that always returns true as the second parameter